# VIM Regex move text to up? VIM Golf

Tags: regex, vim

can anyone tell me how I can solve this in vim? 
I can see where the line starts with the space, but moving the text up doesn't work.

```
|-
| 
| 199
| TNET
  revenue
| Most
  Recent (Last)
| Purchase
| Counter
| Enabled
|-
| 
| 200
| Page
  Category (eVar 30)
| Most
  Recent (Last)
| Visit
| Text
  String
| Enabled
|-
```

I wanna create this:

```
|-
| 
| 199
| TNET revenue
| Most Recent (Last)
| Purchase
| Counter
| Enabled
|-
| 
| 200
| Page Category (eVar 30)
| Most Recent (Last)
| Visit
| Text String
| Enabled
|-
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to do the trick: `:%s/n  / /`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:global` (actually `:g!`) and `:join`:

```
:g!/^|/-1,.join
```

Explanations:

- `:g/{pat}/{cmd}` runs a command, `{cmd}`, on every line matching the pattern, `{pat}`
- `:g` is short of `:global`
- `:g!/{pat}/{cmd}` runs a command on every line that does *not* match the pattern.
- `:vglobal` (`:v` for short) is the same as `:g!`
- Use `:join` for the `{cmd}` in `:g!/{pat}/{cmd}`
- `:[range]join` will join a range, `[range]` of lines. Similar to `J` in normal mode. `:j` for short.
- `{start},{end}` - a range takes a start line and and end line
- `-1,.` is the range for `-1,.join`
- `-1` means `-1` from the current line
- `.` is the current line
- In `-1` the `1` can be assumed so it can become just `-`
- `,.` can also be assumed

Shortening everything the command becomes:

```
:v/^|/-j
```

I wouldn't worry too much about golfing. The most important thing is to recognize a problem and learning how overcome it.

For more help see:

```
:h :v
:h :j
:h :range
```

Comment: Very interesting construct. 
Can you still tell me why you use a Hyphen (bindestrich) and a small j? 
Join uses a big J
According to the instructions it has to be a big J.

`-j`

Comment: using  `j` to the previous line. `- select previous line` <br/> Thanks